# Python disable keyboard input

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

Is there a way to disable (keyboard) input on windows with python. I would like to convert this program to exe and the

> from ctypes import *
>
> ok = windll.user32.BlockInput(True) #enable block

method is not suitable for that (as it needs admin privileges). I looked at other articles with described how using the **pyHook** would work. Unfortunatelly this method is a bit old and does not work for me anymore, it just makes the mouse and keyboard lag a little bit.

There is a working method by just putting keystrokes (from for example the pynput library) in a while loop, so it just spams keystrokes and the user can not overwrite this by typing lets say alt+f4. This is a very dirty way and I would like a cleaner way(this method causes the computer to lag for a minute because it cant comprehend that amount of input in such a short time)

Comment: I'll ignore the obvious question of why, would you want this? The approach will depend on the underlying OS, which I may assume to be Windows, due to the `ctypes`? The following question would be are you specifically trying to disable the drivers, or only trying to prevent normal key presses (thus ignoring special keys, such as the windows key, which will not be blocked)?

Comment: @Thymen Yes this is meant for windows. The goal is to block everything especially the f-keys (f1),control and alt

Answer (score 0):

```
#### Blocking Keyboard ####
import keyboard

#blocks all keys of keyboard
for i in range(150):
    keyboard.block_key(i)
```